# Designing Game of Life using classes C++

Tags: c++, conways-game-of-life

for my final project in my intro C++ class we have to design a version of Game of Life using classes and file I/O. I have been given some beginning functions/instructions but can't even begin to understand where to start or if I am missing other functions to get started. I've included the instructions given and what I have so far. I don't necessarily need the whole thing laid out for me, but if I could just have a little help on how to get started, that would be great.

Instructions:Since the project is in chapter 7, the book’s version doesn’t work with classes and it doesn’t have any file IO. Let’s
address the file IO first. On the project download page in addition to the usual items there will be two data files
containing very simple life community specifications. The files have the following format: first item in the file is the
number of rows the community requires, second item in the file is the number of columns the community requires, third
item is the LIFE community which is stored as ‘.’ (dead) or ‘O’ (alive) characters in the array shape specified by the
preceding two values. 
In order for your project to work with these inputs you will need to specify a two dimensional array. The book specifies a
22 by 80 array. The GTA project uses a 50 by 100 (row by col) array. So long as your array is larger than the size specified
by the input, your code will work with the input. After creating the array, the code reads in the data from the input and
fills out your LIFE community array with a small twist. The book suggests filling in the grid directly with asterisks for live
cells and blanks for dead cells. We will use class objects instead.
The normal implementation of LIFE uses two identical arrays. One stores the now generation and one is used to store
the next generation. (see the book pgs 446 & 447) We will be using one array which contains LIFE cell objects made from
the simplest useful class we could think of. Our class objects will contain two Boolean data items that store the cell’s life
condition and one function which will age the cell.
Your LIFE community’s size should be square and an edge length is define globally as const int edge=#. Your class is
named cell and contains the public boolean variables aod_d0, aod_d1 and the void function age(). Create a general
function that counts the number of living neighbors of a cell and declare its type with the following declaration: int
nbors_sum(cell[edge][edge], int, int, int, int);. Your LIFE community ages a day at a time so create a general function that
reads cells at d0 and determines whether that cell is alive or dead (aod) at d1. It’s declaration is: void oneday(cell[edge]
[edge], int, int);. The oneday function will call the nbors_sum function. The GTA version has a fair amount of code in
main() including file input and the while(true) display loop.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

const int edge=20;

class cell{
public:
    bool aod_d0, aod_d1;
    int nbors_sum(cell[edge][edge],int,int,int,int);
    void oneday(cell[edge][edge],int,int);

int main()
{
    ifstream in;
in.open("glidergun.txt");
if(in.fail())
{
cout <<"Input file failed to open.\n";
return 1;
}
oneday()

in.close();

    return 0;
}

void age();

int nbors_sum(cell[edge][edge],int,int,int,int);

void oneday(cell[edge][edge],int,int){

}
```

Comment: Format your code.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what this means? I'm sorry, I'm pretty new to C++ and very new to the website.

Comment: @OliviaVaca There's a button in the editor that helps you format the code. If you need to see how question should look like, then just look around, there's plenty of examples ;)

Comment: @OliviaVaca By the way, you should avoid posting assignment instructions. You should write a question about a specific thing that don't work in your code, no one is gonna make a whole assignment for you and can result in your question being deleted. Questions which content as been copied and paste are also discouraged.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot Thank you, and I apologize. I didn't expect anyone to do the whole code, but I can understand how it could be seen as that and certainly can see why it would be a problem. I think I will just be removing the question since I don't have a concise question.

Answer (score 2):

It's not so hard - that's a pretty common excercise, so there's a lot of material on the Web. Just check Wikipedia, for example, to get an idea and see some animations of this "Game" in motion:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life

As a starting point, I  would suggest that you do the following:

1. Make your program read in a file and store the data within a 2D
   array, as suggested by the excercise
2. Make your program print the
   resulting 2D array to the console (standard output)

If you manage to get those two steps done, by the point you proceed you will already have a better understanding of what this is all about.

My general suggestion would be that you, if you face a problem like that where you don't know what to do, just start by doing the very obvious things that need to be done anyway (such as the reading the file, in this case). By doing that, you will get familiar with the rest on the way.